# How to resolve mule context properties in DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy

Tags: mule

How do you access mule context properties in DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy. 
here is the declaration of my context property in my mule config.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/mule-standalone-3.4.0/conf/AppBus.properties" />
```

please advise.

regards
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

You can access them via the Spring Property Placeholder syntax: ${my.property}. Such as:

```
<catch-exception-strategy name="unhandled-exceptions">
   <logger level="ERROR" message="${my.property}"
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

More info here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Parameters+in+Your+Configuration+Files

Comment: Hi, i noted catch exception strategy was not working for runtime exception like connector failures. a suggested solution on mulesoft forum was to use a java bean which extends defaultsystemexceptionstrategy. the fix has worked, but now i am looking for a way to capture context parameters, as one suggested action item is to send a email to admin to notify of this failure.

Comment: Are these accessible on mulecontext. please confirm

Comment: This is sorted now. found a solution. my lame skills on spring are such a bottleneck :)